# Passing an environment variable when fetching a dbus object instance through python

Tags: python, environment-variables, dbus, upstart

I am using python to determine the status of an upstart job on Ubuntu.

I've recently changed the upstart job so that it has an Instance stanza as such: `instance $some_var`. As expected, my code no longer works.

If I try:

```
path = upstart.GetJobByName("test", dbus_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6")                                         
job = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.Upstart", path)                           
path = job.GetInstance([], dbus_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job")
```

It fails telling me `dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Unknown parameter: some_var`

I need to pass the some_var environment variable to the dbus interface. How might I do that? Setting it in os.environ doesn't appear to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think `job.GetInstance(["some_var=some_value"])` should work. At least this works fine for me:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system /com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs/tty \
          --dest=com.ubuntu.Upstart \
          com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job.GetInstance array:string:"TTY=/dev/tty2"
```

(tty service was defined with `instance $TTY`)

Also check the description of `env` argument for [com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job.Start](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/DBusInterface#com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job.Start).